# showmodaldialog polyfill : how to pass value to parent window and dialog closed by calling a function?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

There is problem in `Google Chrome` that showmodaldialog doesn't work so that I use `showmodaldialog.js` from [polyfill](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog/blob/gh-pages/showModalDialog.js).

I have two aspx page, one for parent window page `parentpage.aspx` and one for pop up in dialog `emplsearch.aspx`.  The dialog works but I am having problem in passing value from dialog to parent window and the dialog cannot be closed by clicking `imbSelect` imagebutton on click javascript function on `emplsearch.aspx`. I try to use something like this:

```
function quitBox(cmd, msg) {

    if (cmd == 'quit') {
        open(location, '_self').close(); // this works for firefox, but chrome doesnt work
        dialog.close();  // error in console in here... dialog doesnt closed in chrome

       setValuesToParent(msg); // start to pass value to parent window
    }
    return false;
}

function setValuesToParent(msg) {

    parent.window.document.getElementById('txbPinjamBy').value = msg[2];  // this doesnt work too...  error : Cannot set property 'value' of null
    window.opener.setValues(msg); // this is the important line 

};
```

thanks

Comment: im sorry...  thanks btw

Comment: i give up.. i finally use jquery ui.. more simple and easy

Comment: i wont delete it cus i want to know the answer actually,,, maybe someday i use polyfill again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the value from the modal document (`emplsearch.aspx`) to the parent document (`parentpage.aspx`), provided that they are in the [same origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), just invoke:

```
function quitBox(cmd, msg) {
    if (cmd == 'quit') {
        window.returnValue = msg;
        parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close();
    }
}
```

Then, in the parent document, invoke the modal like this:

```
var retVal = window.showModalDialog('emplsearch.aspx');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the model dialog doesn't returns the values. below code is used in dialog

```
window.returnValue = indexName + "$$" + selArrString;

var agentStr = navigator.userAgent;
if (agentStr.indexOf("Chrome") >- 1) {
    // Based on their suggestion I added this line 
    parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close();
    // (In order to close the dialog from inside of it, invoke                         
    //     parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close();
    // provided that both documents have the same origin.)
} else {
    self.close();
}
```